# Five unique pages lead to one page. Can I change the <h1> according to the page they came from?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have five unique forms each on a page of HTML. They then go to a PHP file to send the e-mail of data. Next they go to the HTML thank you page. I am hoping to change the heading according to which form they just submitted.
For example, if they submit a review, the  should read "Thank you for your review" etc.
Technically all of these are saved as php files but only the e-mail page has php items.
Like `<?php echo("<p>". $mail->getMessage()."</p>"); ?>`

Comment: Make them go to a PHP page instead and use session data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should redirect to another php file and pass a parameter on url. Example:

**sendemail.php**

```
<?php
/** After send the email, check what kind form is (I don't know how do you check this).
This example is just to show you: */

if ($formType == 'review') {

   $type = 'review';

} else if ($formType == 'anothertype') {

   $type = 'anothertype';

}

header('Location: /thankspage.php?type=' . $type);
?>
```

**thankspage.php**

```
<?php

$type = $_GET['type'];

if ($type == 'review') {

   echo '<h1>Thanks for your review</h1>';

} else if($type == 'anothertype') {

   echo '<h1>Thanks for your anothertype</h1>';

}
?>
```

Comment: I got this to work, thank you! I have the five unique forms and each of them call their own php file to send the SMTP message. Within that php file I added 
$type = "review";
header('Location: thankTest.php?type=' . $type);
I did not need to test each since they had their own file. Then the thankspage.php works great!

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you.. Have a great day

Comment: Since each of the five sendmail.php pages are unique, I was able to skip the if statements altogether and enter the "type" directly into the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

One way put a hidden field in your forms that'll get passed with the other form data. Then put an if statement on the thank you page and echo the appropriate message.
However, that'll only work either if you change the thank you page to php or change the page that receives and processes the form data to echo the thank you message as well